# Apostrophe stops entry, suggestions have been confusing

Tags: php, html

When I first came here I knew less than nothing.  Now I'm somewhat functional.  I've asked for help on this issue before but the variety of answers I've received have turned out to be more confusing than helpful.

I'm a DJ and I have set up a database for my music on my web space.  I built an HTML form to enter the info for each song.  Unless you know the address you can't find the form.  However, when I hit an apostrophe it fails to write.  I have been given a host of remedies (PDO, htmlentities, sanitize, etc.) but as I read more about them I'm told they are depreciated.  Or I get suggestions to move over to PDO.  I'm still trying to learn PHP and at my age that's all I can handle right now.

Could someone please just tell me what commands I need to use to “sanitize” (if that's right) the input so MySQL will accept it?  Or tell me a location where I can learn the syntax to make it work. No one else uses the form and if someone found it there's no big deal as I copy the DB to my home computer after I'd entered more music.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)